# Load files into a ListBox

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am trying to load files with an extension .csv into a ListBox but my code is not working on Android platform. What's wrong with the code?

```pascal
procedure LoadFileList(aFiles: TStringList; sPath: string; sMask: string = '*.*');
var
iIndex: integer;
SearchRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  if sPath[Length(sPath)] <> '\' then
     sPath := sPath + '\';

     iIndex := FindFirst(sPath+sMask, faArchive, SearchRec);

     while iIndex = 0 do begin
           aFiles.Add(SearchRec.Name);
           iIndex := FindNext(SearchRec);
     end;

     FindClose(SearchRec);
end;
```

Usage:

```
LoadFileList(TStringList(ListBox1.Items), TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, '*.csv');
```

Comment: Do not reinvent wheels and have a look at [`System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles). It is worth to have a deeper look at the whole `IOUtils` unit, it works surprisingly very well ;o)

Comment: And you must not cast the `TListBox.Items` to `TStringList`. Instead change argument `aFiles` to `TStrings` and you do not need any cast

Comment: @SirRufo: you should have posted those as an answer (with example) instead of as comments.

Comment: Your bigger problem is that you say "is not working" as if that is enough to explain the problem. That indicates that you have not yet learnt how to debug and inspect a problem. My advice is to concentrate on developing that skill, and then you'll find so many things easier.

Comment: Thank you @SirRufo I checked it already and seems it pretty simple to use. :)

Answer (score 1):

since you are using XE7 you have access to IOUtils. Then this will do the trick for you:

```
uses
  IOUtils;

procedure LoadFileList(aFiles: TStrings; sPath: string; sMask: string = '*.*');
var
  aFile: string;
begin
  aFiles.Clear;
  for aFile in TDirectory.GetFiles(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(sPath), sMask) do
    aFiles.Add(aFile)
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

"Does not work" is a very unclear description, but the '\' looks very suspicious. Linux uses a '/' instead. Also the strings are zero based on Delphi for Android/iOS.

Instead of

```
  if sPath[Length(sPath)] <> '\' then
     sPath := sPath + '\';
```

use the platform independent version:

```
  sPath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(sPath);
```